# How to convert file size to human readable and print with other columns?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to convert the 5th column in this command output to human readable format.
For ex if this is my input :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bhagyaraj bhagyaraj  280000   Jun 17 18:34 demo1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bhagyaraj bhagyaraj  2800000  Jun 17 18:34 demo2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bhagyaraj bhagyaraj  28000000 Jun 17 18:35 demo3
```

To something like this :

```
-rw-rw-r--  280K demo1
-rw-rw-r--  2.8M demo2
-rw-rw-r--  28M  demo3
```

I tried this command, but this will return only the file size column.

```
ls -l | tail -n +2 |awk '{print $5 | "numfmt --to=si"}'
```

`ls` is just for example my use case is very huge and repeated execution must be avoided

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Use the `-h, --human-readable` flag: `ls -lh`

Comment: @joshmeranda `-h` will use binary prefixes, not decimal like this

Comment: Ope missed that, add `--si`: `ls -lh --si`

Comment: I wanted to use this with dpkg -c option for deb files. ls -l was just an example which output is similar to dpkg -c @joshmeranda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `-h --si`

```
  -h, --human-readable       with -l and -s, print sizes like 1K 234M 2G etc.
      --si                   likewise, but use powers of 1000 not 1024
```

So the command would be

```
ls -lh --si | tail -n +2
```

---

If you don't use `ls` and the command you intend to run doesn't have an option similar to `-h --si` in `ls` then `numfmt` already has the [`--field` option](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html) to specify which column you want to format. For example

```
$ df | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 numfmt --header --field 2-4 --to=si
Filesystem              1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          66M          0        66M   0% /dev
tmpfs                         14M       7.2K        14M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv--0        4.1G       3.7G       416M  90% /
tmpfs                        5.2K          4       5.2K   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme2n1p1               524K       5.4K       518K   2% /boot/efi
```

Unfortunately although `numfmt` does try to preserve the columnation, it fails if there are some large variation in the line length after inserting group separators like you can see above. So sometimes you might still need to reformat the table with [`column`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html)

```
df | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 numfmt --header --field 2-4 --to=si | column -t -R 2,3,4,5
```

The `-R 2,3,4,5` option is for right alignment, but some `column` versions like [the default one in Ubuntu](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column) don't support it so you need to remove that

---

Alternatively you can also use `awk` to format only the columns you want, for example column 5 in case of `ls`

```
$ ls -l demo* | awk -v K=1e3 -v M=1e6 -v G=1e9 'func format(v) {
  if (v > G) return v/G "G"; else if (v > M) return v/M "M";
  else if (v > K) return v/K "K"; else return v
} { $5 = format($5); print $0 }' | column -t
-rw-rw-r--  1  ph  ph  280K  Jun  18  09:23  demo1
-rw-rw-r--  1  ph  ph  2.8M  Jun  18  09:24  demo2
-rw-rw-r--  1  ph  ph  28M   Jun  18  09:23  demo3
-rw-rw-r--  1  ph  ph  2.8G  Jun  18  09:30  demo4
```

And column 2, 3, 4 in case of `df`

```
# M=1000 and G=1000000 because df output is 1K-block, not bytes
$ df | awk -v M=1000 -v G=1000000 'func format(v) {
  if (v > G) return v/G "G"; else if (v > M) return v/M "M"; else return v
}
{
  # Format only columns 2, 3 and 4, ignore header
  if (NR > 1) { $2 = format($2); $3 = format($3); $4 = format($4) }
  print $0
}' OFS="\t" | column -t
Filesystem              1K-blocks  Used      Available  Use%  Mounted                 on
udev                    65.8273G   0         65.8273G   0%    /dev
tmpfs                   13.1772G   7M        13.1702G   1%    /run
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv--0   4073.78G   3619.05G  415.651G   90%   /
tmpfs                   65.8861G   0         65.8861G   0%    /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.12M      4         5.116M     1%    /run/lock
tmpfs                   65.8861G   0         65.8861G   0%    /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme2n1p2          999.32M    363.412M  567.096M   40%   /boot
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 1 :

if you need just a barebones module for byte size formatting (it's setup for base-2 now but modifying it for `--si` should be trivial):

```
    {m,g}awk '
    BEGIN { OFS="="
          _____=log(__=(_+=_+=_^=_)^(____=++_))
    
    } gsub("[.]0+ bytes", 
               " -bytes-", 
        $(!__*($++NF = sprintf("%#10.*f %s" ,____, 
          (_ = $!!__) /  __^(___=int(log(_)/_____)), 
          !___ ? "bytes" : substr("KMGTPEZY",___,!!__)"iB"))))^!__'
```

=

```
734                         734 -bytes-
180043                      175.82324 KiB
232819                      227.36230 KiB
421548373                   402.01986 MiB
838593829                   799.74540 MiB
3739382399                    3.48257 GiB

116601682159                108.59378 GiB
147480014471                137.35147 GiB
11010032230111               10.01357 TiB
19830700070261               18.03592 TiB
111120670776601             101.06366 TiB
15023323323323321            13.34339 PiB

85255542224555233            75.72213 PiB
444444666677766611          394.74616 PiB
106941916666944416909        92.75733 EiB
111919999919911191991        97.07513 EiB
767777766776776776777767    650.33306 ZiB
5558888858993555888686669     4.59821 YiB
```

========================

this is probably waaaay overkill, but I wrote it a while back, which can calculate the human-readable value, as well as comma formatted of raw byte value, supporting everything from **`kilo-bit`** to ***`yotta-byte`***

with options for :

- `base 2` or `base 10` (enter **`10`** or **`"M/m"`** for metric)
- `bytes` (**`B`**)  or `bits` (**`b`**)

The only thing that needs to be hard coded in are the letters themselves, since they grow linearly upon either

- every 3rd power of 10 (`1,000`), or
- every 5th power of  4 (`1,024`)

.

```
    {m,g}awk '

    BEGIN {
     1      FS = OFS = "="
    }
2302812  $!NF = substr(bytesformat($2, 10, "B"), 1, 15)\
                substr(bytesformat($2,  2, "B"), 1, 15)\
                       bytesformat($2,  2, "b")'


    # Functions, listed alphabetically

6908436  function bytesformat(_,_______,________,__, ___, ____, _____, ______)
    {
6908436     _____=__=(____^=___*=((____=___+=___^= "")/___)+___+___)
6908436      ___/=___
6908436     sub("^0+","",_)

6908436      ____=_____-= substr(_____,index(_____,index(_____,!__))) * (_______~"^(10|[Mm])$")
6908436     _______=length((____)____)^(________~"^b(it)?$")

6908436     if ((____*__) < (_______*_)) { # 6906267
24438981        do {
24438981            ____*=_____
24438981            ++___
            } while ((____*__) < (_______*_))
        }
6908436     __=_
6908436     sub("(...)+$",             ",&", __)
6908436     gsub("[^#-.][^#-.][^#-.]", "&,", __)
6908436     gsub("[,]*$|^[,]+",          "", __)
6908436     sub("^[.]",                "0&", __)

6908436     return \
            sprintf("%10.4f %s%s | %s byte%.*s", 
                    _=="" ? +_:_/(_____^___)*_______,
                    substr("KMGTPEZY", ___, _^(_<_)), 
                    --_______?"b":"B",__==""?+__:__,(_^(_<_))<_,"s")
    }
```

|

In this sample, it's showing metric bytes, binary bytes, binary bits, and raw input byte value :

```
  180.0430 KB |  175.8232 KB |    1.3736 Mb | 180,043 bytes
  232.8190 KB |  227.3623 KB |    1.7763 Mb | 232,819 bytes
  421.5484 MB |  402.0199 MB |    3.1408 Gb | 421,548,373 bytes
  838.5938 MB |  799.7454 MB |    6.2480 Gb | 838,593,829 bytes
 
    3.7394 GB |    3.4826 GB |   27.8606 Gb | 3,739,382,399 bytes
  116.6017 GB |  108.5938 GB |  868.7502 Gb | 116,601,682,159 bytes
  147.4800 GB |  137.3515 GB |    1.0731 Tb | 147,480,014,471 bytes

   11.0100 TB |   10.0136 TB |   80.1085 Tb | 11,010,032,230,111 bytes
   19.8307 TB |   18.0359 TB |  144.2873 Tb | 19,830,700,070,261 bytes
  111.1207 TB |  101.0637 TB |  808.5093 Tb | 111,120,670,776,601 bytes
   
   15.0233 PB |   13.3434 PB |  106.7471 Pb | 15,023,323,323,323,321 bytes
   85.2555 PB |   75.7221 PB |  605.7771 Pb | 85,255,542,224,555,233 bytes
  444.4447 PB |  394.7462 PB |    3.0840 Eb | 444,444,666,677,766,611 bytes
  
  106.9419 EB |   92.7573 EB |  742.0586 Eb | 106,941,916,666,944,416,909 bytes
  111.9200 EB |   97.0751 EB |  776.6010 Eb | 111,919,999,919,911,191,991 bytes

  767.7778 ZB |  650.3331 ZB |    5.0807 Yb | 767,777,766,776,776,776,777,767 bytes
    5.5589 YB |    4.5982 YB |   36.7856 Yb | 5,558,888,858,993,555,888,686,669 bytes
```